# Simple PHP fetch all data in table not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok so I don't know what the hell is going on I'm just trying to list all the data in a table and it's just not working I have tried a few different ways and I'm not getting any error messages and I have been over the syntax many times.

Here is the code:

```
// Connect to database
$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
if (!$dbc) 
    die("Could not connect" . mysql_error());

// Select database
$dbc_dbselect = mysql_select_db( "contactmanager", $dbc );
if (!$dbc_contactmanager)
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

// Query database
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER by name";

$result = mysql_query($query);

// start a table tag in the HTML
echo '<table>';

// Create a loop to loop through results
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   

// Print the results
echo '<tr>'.'<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['Address'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['Phone'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['Mobile'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$row['Mobile'].'</td>'.'</tr>';  
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML


mysql_close($dbc);
```

And this is the output result in firefox:

```
 '; //Create a loop to loop through results while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo ''.''.$row['Name'].''.''.$row['Address'].''.''.$row['Phone'].''.''.$row['Mobile'].''.''.$row['Mobile'].''.''; //$row['index'] the index here is a field name } echo ""; //Close the table in HTML mysql_close($dbc); ?>
```

Database and table
[image: This is the Database and table]

Comment: Where does `$dbc_contactmanager` come from?

Comment: Can you change the "$result = mysql_query($query);" to "$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());" and let us know if is throwing any error. @SverriM.Olsen has a good point too.

Comment: probably some php start or end tag is missing..

Comment: Yeah I think $result is coming back blank but funny part is when I add die it doesn't do anything.

Comment: have you checked your script in other browser like `opera or chrome`??

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome, exactly the same result.

Comment: your apache server is not running.. Please start it.. :-)

Comment: Yeah seems like maybe it is not, although xampp says it is and nothing has change since it was working 30 minutes ago and I tried restarting my computer and starting apache again and still scripts aren't working

Comment: yeah I also think so theres some problem with your apache.. try using `wamp`..

Comment: Ok so I got it all sorted thanks all for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the third parameter i.e: `password`

```
$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                                           ^----Here
```

it should be:

```
mysql_select_db( "contactmanager", $dbc );
```

Comment: Tried it, no change :(

Comment: Nope no change. my other add contact script works fine and uses very similar code.

Answer (score 0):

Provide password as a third parameter whatever it is set on your system in double quotes

```
  $dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "<DBMS_PASSWORD>");
```

if not set , leave double quotes empty ("").